# Delete item in NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm using the `HSImageSidebarView`, when an image is tapped, an `AlertView` will pop-up if you want to delete it.
This is how it deletes its image shown in the sidebar:

```
-(void)sidebar:(HSImageSidebarView *)sidebar didTapImageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex {
    NSLog(@"Touched image at index: %u", anIndex);
    if (sidebar.selectedIndex == anIndex) {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete image?"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        self.actionSheetBlock = ^(NSUInteger selectedIndex) {
            if (selectedIndex == sheet.destructiveButtonIndex) {
                [sidebar deleteRowAtIndex:anIndex];
                self.actionSheetBlock = nil;
            }
        };

        [sheet showFromRect:[sidebar frameOfImageAtIndex:anIndex]
                     inView:sidebar
                   animated:YES];

    }
}
- (void)sidebar:(HSImageSidebarView *)sidebar didRemoveImageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex {
    NSLog(@"Image at index %d removed", anIndex);
    [images removeObjectAtIndex:anIndex];
}
```

BTW, my images are from `NSDocumentDirectory`, but what I wanted to add is when an image is tapped in the side bar, it also deletes the image in `NSDocumentDirectory`.

I know this is how to delete the image in the `NSDocumentDirectory`, but i dont know how to use it in the above code.

```
- (void)removeImage:(NSString*)fileName {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", fileName]];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"image removed");
}
```

Comment: do u want to delete image when when alertview;s button is pressed.

Comment: @safecase yes i want to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a list of file names along with your images.  Or, in your case, I saw in your last question that your filenames are predictable.  So just substitute Document Directory/*image+index*.png for `fullPath` in the above example.  If that is not the case anymore, then you need to keep track of the filenames when you read them in, and store them in another array with the same indices.

Comment: You will never accomplish anything if you just keep asking for code.  You have sample code already above.  I'm just telling you how to alter it.  Your images are just image1, image2, image3 right?  In that case you can build the string using NSString `stringWithFormat:` (check the documentation) using the index that got passed into the method (`anIndex`)

Comment: `NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", anIndex]];` like this right?

Comment: Then you need to edit your question...and say more than "it is not working"

Comment: I said say more than "it is not working"...the error message would be helpful (from the last argument of `deleteFileAtPath`)

Comment: I don't quite get the `deleteFileAtPath` sir,

Comment: I meant `removeItemAtPath` ><

Comment: no error was logging in the debugger. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: NSError *error;  [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:&error];  Call method like this, check the error description.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may fix it:

```
 - (void)sidebar:(HSImageSidebarView *)sidebar didRemoveImageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex {
    NSLog(@"Image at index %d removed", anIndex);
```

```
//remove the image from Document dir
[self removeImage:[images objectAtIndex:anIndex]];

//then remove the image from the Array.
[images removeObjectAtIndex:anIndex];
```

}

```
- (void)removeImage:(NSString*)fileName {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", fileName]];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"image removed");
}
```